# Arista switch - Forward multicast traffic from vlan to vlan on different switch ports with different subsets

Tags: switch, forwarding, multicast, packets

I have an Arista DCS-7150S-24-R

1. I got a cross connect from provider X into port #1 (port marked as vlan 100)
2. I got a linux host connected to to the switch at port #2 (port marked as vlan 200)
3. Ports are on different subnets.
4. Port #1 receives multicast traffic which I'm trying to forward to the linux host.

To my understanding, in order for that to happen,

The traffic needs to be routed (forwarded) from vlan100 to vlan200

Would appreciate guidance on how to achieve this

Comment: Ooooh, financial? Market data?

Comment: Can you show your config?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an IP address to the vlan subinterface(s) and add routes to your Linux server to reach the provider's addresses.

E.g.

```
interface Vlan100
   description "Fast Multicast"
   ip address 10.250.10.1/24
   ip pim sparse-mode

interface Vlan200
   description "Application Servers"
   ip address 10.50.25.1/24
   ip pim sparse-mode
```

In the linux host, add routes to reach what you need on the provider's side.